# Laravel crear vista a partir de una consulta en una relación de muchos a uno (la consulta se hace en mucho y se agrupa por los coincidentes en uno)

Tags: laravel, controller, model

Saludos a todos esto es lo que quiero: tengo una tabla arquitect de la cual este es mi modelo:

```
class Arquitect extends Model{
protected $table="arquitects";
protected $fillable=['name', 'identification', 'cell', 'is_enabled'];

public function services(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
}
```

Y una tabla servicios de la cual este es el modelo:

```
class Service extends Model{
    protected $table="services";
    protected $fillable=['number_service', 'service', 'entry_date', 'expiry_date', 'service_status', 'municipality_id', 'arquitect_id','created_at'];

    public function arquitect(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Arquitect');
    }
```

También una tabla municipio pero creo que no es de relevancia ya que obtengo lo que deseo de ella en una variable por un `\Session` este es su modelo:

```
class Municipality extends Model{
    protected $table="municipalities";
    protected $fillable=['name', 'code'];
    public function services(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Service');
    }
}
```

Existen más campos  y más tablas pero los omití para ir solo a lo que deseo.

Lo que hago es hacer un filtro para crear un informe `PDF`. Hago el filtro en la tabla servicio y lo llevo al informe por arquitectos. Esta es mi consulta en el controller:

```
public function crearPDF2( $datos,$urlvista, $filtro){
    $data = $datos;
    $fecha = Carbon::now();
    $fecha1 = $fecha->format('Y-m-d');
    $view = View::make($urlvista, compact('data', 'fecha', 'filtro', 'fecha1'))->render();
    $pdf = App:: make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($view)->setPaper('letter', 'landscape');
    return $pdf->stream('reporte.pdf');
}


public function crearReporteFtermino(){
    $urlvista= "admin.ftermino.pdf";
    $filtro = \Session::get('munic');
    $filtro1 = \Session::get('munic_id');
    $fecha = Carbon::now();
    $arquitects =Arquitect::select('id')->get();
    $services= Service::where('expiry_date','<', $fecha)
                ->where('service_status','=','Iniciado')
                ->where('municipality_id', '=', $filtro1)
    ->whereIn('arquitect_id', $arquitects->toArray())->get();
    $arquitects->each(function ($arquitect){
    $arquitect->services;
    });

    return $this->crearPDF2($services,$urlvista,$filtro);
```

}

esta me funciona bien, pero no se si está bien realizada para llevarla de la forma que quiero a la vista, recoger por arquitecto todos los servicios que estan pasados de la fecha que expira. Es decir Arquitecto X con todos su servicios expirados, Aquitecto Y con todos sus servicios expirados y asi consecutivamente. Si la consulta está bien lo que no sé es crear la vista para este caso. 
Les ruego perdonen mi ignorancia, llevo a penas un mes en este mundo de la programación.

Answer (score 0):

ya logré los resultados que quería, aquí dejo la forma en que me funcionó, para otro más novato que yo en este mundo y le pueda servir, no se si es la más correcta o la más eficiente pero obtengo lo que deseo.
Modifiqué en el controlador la segunda funsión crearReporteFtermino() de esta manera:

```
public function crearReporteFtermino(){
    $urlvista= "admin.ftermino.pdf";
    $filtro = \Session::get('munic');
    $arquitects =Arquitect::select('id','name')->wherehas('services',
        function($serv){
            $filtro1 = \Session::get('munic_id');
            $fecha = Carbon::now();
            $serv-> where('expiry_date','<', $fecha)
                 ->where('service_status','=','Iniciado')
                 ->where('municipality_id', '=', $filtro1);
        })->get();
    $arquitects->each(function ($arquitect){
        $filtro1 = \Session::get('munic_id');
        $fecha = Carbon::now();
        $arquitect->services= Service::where('expiry_date','<', $fecha)
                  ->where('service_status','=','Iniciado')
                  ->where('municipality_id', '=', $filtro1)
                  ->whereIn('arquitect_id', $arquitect->toArray())->get();
    });
```

return $this->crearPDF2($arquitects,$urlvista,$filtro);

}

y mi vista la cree de la manera que Andres Felipe me sugirió en mi primera pregunta la cual me funciona perfecta para selecionar todos los datos de manera general sin filtrar y también se aplica a esta filtrando lo que deseo de servicios, es decir de esta forma:

```
@foreach($data as $arq)
<p>
    <b>Arquitecto:</b> {{$arq->name}}
</p>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Estado</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Servicio</th>
        <th>F.Entrada</th>
        <th>Expira</th>
        <th>Municipio</th>
        <th>Talón</th>
        <th>Importe</th>
        <th>Días</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($arq->services as $service)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $service->service_status}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->client->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->service}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->entry_date}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->expiry_date}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->municipality->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->receipt->number}}</td>
            <td>{{ $service->receipt->amount}}</td>
            <td>{{ ($dias= $fecha->diffInDays($service->expiry_date))}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

@endforeach

Y aquí les dejo una imagen del resultado final en PDF:

[image: Es decir la la cantidad de servicios que los arquitectos tienen sin entregar pasados la fecha en que expira (fecha tope para entregar) y la cantidad de días.]

Es decir la la cantidad de servicios que los arquitectos tienen sin entregar pasados la fecha en que expira (fecha tope para entregar) y la cantidad de días.
Gracias a Todos...